# how to add script in <head> section of prestashop

Tags: service-worker, prestashop-1.7

how to add following code

```
<script src="https://clientcdn.pushchant.com/core/rp.js"></script>  <script>
    _pe.subscribe();
</script>
```

in head section of prestashop 1.7

And also tell me how to add service-worker.js in root directory of prestashop.

or

can be add service-worker.js other than root directory

Answer (score 2):

use this for added css

`$this->context->controller->registerStylesheet(css_key,css_file_src, ['media' => 'all', 'priority' => 150]);`

use this for added js file

`$this->context->controller->registerJavascript(js_key, js_file_src, ['position' => 'head', 'priority' => 150]);`

set position `head` to load js in header tag
or 
set position `bottom` to load js in footer.

here css_key,j_key is a identifier to these css,js files.

Comment: thanks @Kamruzzaman ! its working fine. Could you please tell me how to add service-worker.js in root directory of prestashop in a module.

Comment: can not understand what do you want

Comment: I want to put a js file  with index.php file through module

Comment: I mean relatively at same position

Comment: use this code to load js only index page : 

`if(isset($this->context->controller->php_self) && ($this->context->controller->php_self == 'index')){
 $this->context->controller->registerJavascript(js_key, js_file_src, ['position' => 'head', 'priority' => 150]);
}`